# Need to create a settings file  from which i can fetch values during for loop  

Tags: python, django, loops

I have json data from a url that i converted inti python dictionary and by using for loop i am extracting information from the json data provided by the url.But if  need to add some more print statements i have to edit source code every time .Is there any way that the variables i  am using to fetch json data from the url inside for loop i get from a settings file .which can be any type .

I need to do this because if need to add some changes i do them in the settings file not in the source code

---

from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

import urllib2

import simplejson

responseFromMetataste = urllib2.urlopen("http://metataste.com/do?
action=srch&want=gnr_4dd3faa9237e1e43c5a416f9&nmht=2&ofst=0&card=appMovieCard").read()

parseResponseString = simplejson.loads(responseFromMetataste)

parser = SafeConfigParser()

parser.read("settings.txt")

k=parseResponseString['results']

for y in range(len(k)):
    print "Movie "+str(y+1)
    print ("Movie_Title     :"+(k[y][parser.get('Details','Trailer')][0][parser.get('Movie_Details','M_Title')]))

```
if (parser.get('Movie_Flags','M_url'))=='True' :
    print ("Movie_URL       :"+(k[y][parser.get('Details','Trailer')][0][parser.get('Movie_Details','M_url')]))

if (parser.get('Movie_Flags','M_Id'))=='True' :
    print ("Movie_ID        :"+(k[y][parser.get('Details','Trailer')][0][parser.get('Movie_Details','M_Id')]))

if (parser.get('Movie_Flags','M_Lang'))=='True' :
    print ('Movie_Lang      :'+(k[y][parser.get('Details','Ttl')][parser.get('Details','Languages')][0]))

if (parser.get('Movie_Flags','M_summary'))=='True' :
    print ('Movie_Summary   :'+(k[y][parser.get('Details','Synopsis')]))

if (parser.get('Movie_Flags','M_Genre'))=='True' :
    print ('Movie_Genre     :'+(k[y][parser.get('Details','Genre')][0][parser.get('Movie_Details','M_Genre')]))

if (parser.get('Movie_Flags','Yr_Release'))=='True':
    print ('Year_of_release :'+str(k[y][parser.get('Details','Yor')]))

if (parser.get('Movie_Flags','Poster_Url'))=='True' :
    print ('poster_url      :'+str(k[y][parser.get('Details','Posters')][2][parser.get('Movie_Details','Poster_Url')]))
```

XXXX..........................................XXXX........................................XXXX

settings.txt file

[Details]
Ttl=ttl

Trailer=trailer

Languages=lngs

Synopsis=synp

Genre=gnr

Yor=yr

Posters=posters

[Movie_Flags]

M_Title=True

M_url=True

M_Id=True

M_Lang=True

M_summary=True

M_Genre=True

Yr_Release=True

Poster_Url=True

[Movie_Details]

M_Title=ttl

M_url=url

M_Id=_id

M_Lang=lngs

M_summary=True

M_Genre=nm

Yr_Release=yr

### Poster_Url=url

new settings file

var1=true:title:'sometitle'

var2=true:title:'sometitle'

var3=true:title:'sometitle'

these values should be read from the settings file during for loop
and during for loop i need to fetch these values by passing var1 ,var2 , var3 .......into some function and i need to perform all these steps using python .

Answer (score 0):

You can use any file type mentioned. It only depends on how much code, in terms of efficiency, that you want to write. I assume you will also be maintaining the code!

My suggestion would be to go with a csv file. Read a line and split it for the ',' comma char. The split method should give you an array which has var1, var2, ... etc.

This way you can loop on that array and also pass it to any other method.

Comment: Don't recommend parsing a CSV file by splitting on commas. CSV files are much more complicated than that. There's a `csv` module to deal with them.